# Elemento fixo HTML com scrollToFixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou usando o Plugin scrollToFixed para trabalhar com elementos fixos na tela. O que estou tentando fazer é: tenho uma div e quando o meu cabeçalho chegar a uma determinada altura quero que essa div se mexa junto e quando chegar próximo ao meu rodapé ela pare. A questão é que não estou conseguindo fazer isso com esse plugin. O que estou fazendo:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#divBusca').scrollToFixed({
                marginTop: 20,
                limit: 1725
            });
        });
```

Exemplo do que eu preciso fazer: [Exemplo aqui](http://webquadras.com.br)

Comment: Acho duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4126/129 e/ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27180/129. Provavelmente há outras.

Comment: A blz, vou retirar a pergunta então. Valeu.

Comment: Se as respostas que já existem não resolverem o problema coloca então uma pergunta com o problema específico que não consegues resolver.

Comment: Raphael, melhorei o exemplo na outra resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27180/129

Comment: Deu quase certo, ele só não está respeitando o meu footer, ele ultrapassa.

Comment: Quando dás a tua página como link de exemplo do problema a pergunta fica sem sentido depois de o problema estar resolvido, ou como agora que nada funciona. Cria um jsFiddle, ou adapta o meu para haver um exemplo fixo do problema e podermos ajudar.